# Telerik ASP.NET Ajax control for TimeSpan value

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, rad-controls

What is the most suitable control to allow users to enter and edit TimeSpan value?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an open-ended question, as both depends on the scenario, and is asking a bit of personal opinion.  My suggestion would be to use the RadSlider control if the range is finite and the units are constant (e.g., always asking for seconds or minutes, etc).  For totally flexible ranges it would be better handled via two RadDateTimePicker controls.

Comment: How do you want to use two RadDateTimePicker controls?

Comment: Subtraction operator on two DateTime objects yields a TimeSpan.  Your result would simply be `TimeSpan t1 = RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate.Value - RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate.Value`. You would, of course, have to validate that each control has a value, and which is larger, etc, but you get the idea.

Comment: @DixonD, I think, GuthMD is suggesting two controls because a TimeSpan value implies a beginning time and ending time.

Comment: I've got it, but it is actually not always a case. For example, if you need to specify a period for some repeatable task.

Comment: For just setting such an interval, I'd again recommend RadSlider if options are finite, discrete values.  Otherwise you could use RadNumericTextBox for free-form entry.  If duration can be anything from seconds to days, etc, you could pair that with a dropdown for that selection.